Finding nearest matrix such that the elementwise distance is approximately equal and minimal with constraints?
I am looking for a solution or simply the name for this type of optimisation. Given a real matrix $X$ I want to find some matrix $Y$ of the same dimensions such that the squared difference between any arbitrary two elements from the matrices is approximately equal and minimal. That is $\ (X_{i,j} -Y_{i,j})^2 \sim (X_{n,p} - Y_{n,p})^2  ,\exists i,j,n,p $. Without any constraints obviously $Y=X$.
The main constraints I'm interested in is $Y$ having unit diagonal and real non-negative eigenvalues. Thanks in advance!

Do you care more about the minimality of the difference or the equality? In any case, you can try to solve the minimum of $|X-Y-cE|_F$ over $Y$ and $c$ where $E$ is the all-ones matrix

$
\def\L{{\cal L}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\CR#1{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\tfracLR#1#2{\LR{\tfrac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Let $\o$ denote the all-ones vector and $\CR{x,y}$ the vectorized matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
x = \vc X,\qq y=\vc Y \\
}$$
Then as Exodd suggests, you need to find the least-squares solution of
$$\eqalign{
\LR{y-x} \;=\; \l\o \\
}$$
A closed-form solution exists in terms of the Centering Matrix $\,(C)$
$$\eqalign{
y &= Cx,\qq \l = -\tfracLR{\o^Ty}{n} \\
}$$
If you need to specify further constraints on the diagonal elements and/or eigenvalues of $Y,$ then there isn't a closed-form solution and you must settle for a numerical solution of the constrained problem.
